# How does PM2 manage to run multiple processes listening on the same port?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I wonder how pm2 allows my express app code to run unmodified in parallel processes. When I try to manually start another instance of my express app listening on e.g. port 3000, I always get error that port is already in use.

Does pm2 MODIFY the js code which is run to insert some tweaks in the middle, or does it emulate some sort of VM and then exposes just the one port of pm2 process to the world? What goes on behind the scene?

Answer (score 0):

I came looking for the same answer (when considering performance vs usability of *PM2* vs *Node's cluster*), and found this unanswered. Thus posting for future readers:

from [the horse's mouth](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/):

> The cluster mode allows networked Node.js applications
> (http(s)/tcp/udp server) to be scaled across all CPUs available,
> without any code modifications. This greatly increases the performance
> and reliability of your applications, depending on the number of CPUs
> available. Under the hood, this uses the Node.js cluster module such
> that the scaled application’s child processes can automatically share
> server ports.

Answer (score -3):

PM2 won't allow you to start the same script on the port again. If you use the `pm2 start app.js -f` option to force the script to start again, pm2 will repeatedly try starting up the script but will fail every time since that port is already in use. `pm2 ls` might show that there are two processes running, but in reality the second one is failing continuously and you can confirm the same by running the `pm2 logs` command.

If you're talking about the cluster mode of pm2, in that case pm2 just load balances the requests between multiple child processes using NodeJS's cluster module internally.

Comment: This doesn't explain anything.